# brower is blocking get requests because Access-Control-Allow-Origin not right

Tags: javascript, request-headers

Hi,

I have a script that sends requests and gets response from within my own site, like this:

```
 var socket = io('http://example.com:3000/');
```

however, on the console it says GET is being blocked because Access-Control-Allow-Origin not set right. How can I set the headers right so the request doesnt get blocked?

Thank you.

Comment: The application running on port 3000 has to send the [respective header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to allow this.

Comment: my question is how do I do that?

Comment: I don't know what's running on port 3000 or if you can modify it. Please provide more information.

Comment: its socket.io, a node.js application

Comment: There are well explained example in the documation of socket.io how to handle cors. Depending on the version, they may vary a bit: [v2.x](https://socket.io/docs/v2/handling-cors/), [v3.x](https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/), [v4.x](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/)

Comment: thank you for the info.